# How can I mirror my iPad display wirelessly?

Tags: ipad, ios, wifi, video, airplay

I am looking to display my iPad screen **wirelessly** to an external display to demo applications.  I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZt9pHJQqQE) showing exactly what I want to do with an iPhone but no explanation as to what the hardware dongle used was.

The main thing is that there isn't a wire tethering the user to the external display.

Comment: `Just double-click the Home button, swipe all the way to the right, and select AirPlay Mirroring.`

Answer (score 11):

This is possible using iOS 5 and an Apple TV using AirPlay.

This only works with iPhone 4S and iPad 2 and all video and sound are mirrored wirelessly to any TV that is connected via HDMI downstream from the Apple TV. You do need a wireless network for the two devices to communicate.

> Just double-click the Home button, swipe all the way to the right, and
>   select AirPlay Mirroring.

Reference: http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/airplay.html

Answer (score 5):

**Edited to clarify:** ***On the iPad 1***, unfortunately there's no way to mirror the display without jailbreaking. Even the new Airplay iOS feature only allows the streaming of things specifically sent to the stream by an app, much like the hardware iPad video-out.

Comment: iOS5 will support Airplay mirroring however.  So it will do what he's looking for, it's just not available yet.

Comment: @Jamie Indeed, looking forward to it.

Comment: It is now possible. See @Edward's answer.

Comment: @styfle Indeed it is. Much has changed since February 2011.

Answer (score 2):

Jailbreak, then install [Veency](http://cydia.saurik.com/info/veency/).

Comment: this pretty much answers it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious to find out which of these devices are actually certified by Apple and has a Made for iPhone/iPad stamp.  I've yet to jailbreak my iPad so it's not convenient for me to use a product that will require me to download additional software or hack my iPad.

It seems out of these solutions, only the Air Shuttle from CyWee is "the first and only MFi-certified accessory that enables real-time audio and video transmission from an iPod, iPhone, or iPad."   Found this on their site at: http://cywee.com/products/wireless/air-shuttle/

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is in the making, it just isn't here yet.

Supposedly there's a gaming peripherals company out of the UK named Blaze that will be coming out sometime this April with [a wireless TV-out setup that will mirror what's on an iPad screen](http://www.ipadforums.net/apple-ipad-news/18092-blaze-launches-wireless-tv-out-converter-hdmi-adaptor-ipad-iphone-ipod.html).

Comment: UPDATE: Want to add that there is another company coming out with iPad-to-display wireless connector besides Blaze,  one that will purportedly be released this month: CyWee Air Shuttle http://www.cywee.com or http://www.mirrorop.com/

Answer (score 1):

We made something that might be what you are trying to do.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnM8ciByJps

Comment: That's perfect.  Are they going to be sold anywhere?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can download veency on your iPad2 and chicken vnc on your laptop, connected to the external display. Works great for flipping through pages or pics.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! You've posted this as an answer, which is only for things that directly answer the question asked. If you have a different question, feel free to ask it using the Ask Question button at the top right. I've edited out the question from here. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An app came out just about a month ago called [Reflector](http://reflectorapp.com) that mirrors the iPad display onto your Mac providing that all devices are on the same Wi-fi network (which is easy because with a Mac you can broadcast your wifi and create a network.

Your iPad sees the iMac as an AirPlay compatible device which means that you can mirror everything. Best part of this is that you can use screen recording software on the Mac to capture your content.

Answer (score -3):

Hey we are a young Cupertino based start-up and we wanted you to take a look at our product Prijector. We are Airplay for all your devices and works very well for presenting wirelessly inside conference rooms. Please do check us out at https://prijector. com

Comment: Please have a look at the [FAQ], especially the part about self-promotion.